# Rest : How to handle thousands of same request

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have rest web service which basically takes long as a number and provide whether the number is prime or not ie plain/text true or false.

millions of users are using this service.

Now one user is sending very big number like (15-20 digit number / big number ) and my service is taking time to calculate whether the number is prime or not. That user is sending thousands of requests continuously for the same number. So how to handle these same thousands of requests.

For Example :

Sending 101221323232324343 number in the request and my service is taking let's say 3 sec to find out whether the number is prime or not. Now he is sending 1000 requests per second.

how to handle this case ?

Comment: I guess you can use an in-memory cache.

Comment: There are so many users with different numbers as well....cache gonna be too big...dont think cache is a good solution...

Comment: So you can do magic...: bexause Either You use memory to save processing time or you spare more processing time to each request.... There is no third option , if you have a smart cache approach you can save some memory, not simple put each request into the cache

Comment: To avoid users sending a lot of requests, you have to rate limit them.

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of an evicting in-memory cache tuning its parameters with respect to maximum memory size or TTL. For general info check e.g. [LFU cache eviction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least-frequently_used_(LFU)). There many implementations while I would recommend the [caffeine library](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) by Ben Manes for its efficiency. You could use a DB, but it IO may be more expensive than a new computation in this case, so I'd probably restrict caching to memory only.

Answer (score 2):

You could store values which are larger than a given number of digits in a database. Whenever such a number is received, you can store whether it's prime in the database. You could also use a cache to store the last n different values, so, when a number is requested, you check whether it's too long. If not, simply calculate. If it is too long, search for it in the cache. If it's there, return it. If it's not there, search for it in the database. If it's there, add it to the cache (and possibly remove the oldest value) and return it to the user. If it's not even in the database, calculate it, store it in the database, add it to the cache and return the answer to the user.

Comment: @VJS you are welcome. You might consider accepting it as the correct answer if it solved your problem. Anyway, I wish you good luck in solving this interesting problem.

Comment: That's a great answer. It's a straightforward approach. Just thinking, can we do something else to handle this scenario. I mean, is there any better solution..

Comment: @VJS you can use some additional optimizational techniques. For example, if the sum of the digits is divisible by 3, then the large number is not a prime. If the last digit is pair, then the large number is not prime. If you have another nonprime, which is close-enough to this number, you can check the difference. For instance, if the other non-prime number was divisible by seven and the difference is divisible by seven, then you have a nonprime.

Comment: I would check the IO cost (given highly concurrent lookup) vs. computation time before going for any DB. Also without a reasonable eviction strategy the DB will quickly occupy the whole storage as the problem is unbounded :)

Answer (score -2):

```
@NotThreadSafe 
public CheckIfPrime extends Servelet  {
    private Long lastNumber;
    private Long isLastNumberPrime;

    public Long operation(ServeletRequest req, ServeletResponse res) {
        if(getNumberFromRequest(req) == lastNumber) {
            return isLastNumberPrime;
        } else {
             return checkForPrimeNumber(getNumberFromRequest);
        }
    }

}
```

Use synchronisation primitives to honour the class' invariants and postconditions (one way can be to use `AtomicLong` instead of `Long`)

If you think the number of requests can be too huge (exhausting memory), consider using a distributed cache.

For very high TPS, make your application reactive. The `checkForPrime()`opeeation can be done asynchronously. Why block the calling thread?

Comment: The probability of hitting the same value as the last one given the sheer number of requests is next to zero, so this optimization is useless.

Comment: Oh, why do you think it will be next to zero? As the OP mentioned, there can be thousands of requests that contain the same number.

Comment: The same is not the last: as OP said "millions of users are using the service" and surely there will be thousands repetitions of thousands equal numbers, so effectively it will be a new number every time as compared to the last one. Also, your example is not thread safe: you should use an atomic reference for the pair of value/indicator and swap that correspondingly.

Comment: In that case, can we use a ConcurrentHashMap containing the number and its boolean result?

Comment: See my (separate) answer, given the problem is unbounded your code will quickly run out of memory on a standard map, concurrent or not.

Comment: Oh so you are using a cache with expiry. Makes sense.